# Pass through http authentication with mysqli_connect in php

Tags: php, mysql, http, authentication

I am facing a little problem when i am trying to access to a remote server (no localhost) for my sql database. Normally, we need to pass throught a http authentication to access to the mysqladmin page, but i managed to go to the page with that line : `http://user:password@site.net/mysqladm...`
And it works.
I have also disabled the login confirmation's browser for the HTTP authentication.
Now, when i want to make it work on my php code, it is not working.
In localhost, it is working.

This is what I write on my code :

```
mysqli_connect('http://httpuser:httppassword@site.net/mysqladmin/index.php', 'root', 'password', 'db');
```

Do you have any issues for my problem ?

Regards,

Comment: Do your server have access to the remote database?

Comment: Yes, the server has accesses to db :)

Comment: Take a look at the answer of @Jojo Hav. That's probably your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mysqli_connect](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.construct.php) expects a host or IP address, to a MySQL database server, as first parameter.

You instead are passing a http link `site.net/mysqladmin/index.php`, which is just a administration backend that connects to the configured MySQL server. You need to determine the IP of the MySQL server which the backend is connecting to. Make sure that the firewall allows incoming connections on your configured port (default: 3306)

```
<?php
    mysqli_connect('IP or host of the MySQL server', 'root', 'password', 'db');
?>
```